# How to compare two columns and sum the amount based on condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe like this.

```
id    trade_id    TradeDate  SettleDate    amt
3136      6828      20200616    20200620  15000000.0  
3136      6828      20200616    20200620  15000000.0   
3136      6828      20200620    20200620  15000000.0    
3136      6934      20200623    20200630  15000000.0    
3136      7007      20200623    20200630  30000000.0     
3136      7050      20200625    20200630  25000000.0
```

For each **id**, need to check when the trade was settled.For a given id there could be multiple settlement. A new column has to be added **`settlement_bal`**. when the trade is settled then we have to add all the amount till that day and put that into settlement_bal, if the trade is not settled then the settlement_bal would be zero.

For this example for **`id=3136`**, first settlement happened on **`20th June`**,So settlement balance would be **`zero`** till 19th June.Next settlement was on **`30th June`**.Output would be to fill up the missing dates as well.

```
id          SettleDate   settlement_bal
3136         20200616    0
3136         20200617    0  
3136         20200618    0
...          ........    0
3136         20200620    45000000.0
3136         20200621    45000000.0
3136         20200622    45000000.0
....         ........    ..........
3136         20200629    45000000.0
3136         20200630    115000000.0
```

trade settlement can happened on the same day, later or even before as well.How can I achieve this?

Comment: And what have you tried?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
#00.module

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# 0. data

d=[['3136' ,'6828' ,'20200616', '20200620', 15000000],  
['3136' ,'6828' ,'20200616', '20200620', 15000000],   
['3136' ,'6828' ,'20200620', '20200620', 15000000],    
['3136' ,'6934' ,'20200623', '20200630', 15000000],    
['3136' ,'7007' ,'20200623', '20200630', 30000000],     
['3136' ,'7050' ,'20200625', '20200630', 25000000]] 



data=pd.DataFrame(d,columns='id trade_id TradeDate SettleDate amt'.split())
data['TradeDate']=pd.to_datetime(data['TradeDate'] ,format='%Y%m%d')
data['SettleDate']=pd.to_datetime(data['SettleDate'] ,format='%Y%m%d')

print(data)

# 1.1 make a dataframe t which has each id containing whole Date

min=data[['TradeDate', 'SettleDate']].min().min() #min Date
max=data[['TradeDate', 'SettleDate']].max().max() #max Date
t=pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start=min, end=max)).rename(columns={0:'SettleDate'})
t=t.merge(data['id'].drop_duplicates(),how='cross')

# 1.2 merge

result=data.groupby(['id', 'SettleDate']).sum().cumsum().reset_index().merge(t,on=['id', 'SettleDate'], how='outer')
result=result.sort_values(['id','SettleDate'])
print(result) # not result, but intermediete step

# 1.3 fill nan

result['amt']=result[['id','amt']].groupby('id').fillna(method='ffill')
result.loc[result['amt'].isna(),'amt']=0
result=result.rename(columns={'amt':'settlement_bal'})
print(result) #result
```